# Crash that not able to get

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios5, ios7

```
    thread #1: tid = 0xba03, 0x3a156b26 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend + 6, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread, stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xa000000c)
    frame #0: 0x3a156b26 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend + 6
    frame #1: 0x2fcfc654 CoreFoundation`CFRelease + 556
    frame #2: 0x2fd07b44 CoreFoundation`-[__NSArrayM dealloc] + 156
    frame #3: 0x3a166b0a libobjc.A.dylib`objc_object::sidetable_release(bool) + 174
    frame #4: 0x3a158006 libobjc.A.dylib`(anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 358
    frame #5: 0x2fcff980 CoreFoundation`_CFAutoreleasePoolPop + 16
    frame #6: 0x3253724c UIKit`_wrapRunLoopWithAutoreleasePoolHandler + 36
    frame #7: 0x2fd971cc CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 20
    frame #8: 0x2fd94b70 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoObservers + 284
    frame #9: 0x2fd94eb2 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 730
    frame #10: 0x2fcffc26 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 522
    frame #11: 0x2fcffa0a CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
    frame #12: 0x349de282 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 138
    frame #13: 0x325a3048 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1136
    frame #14: 0x000ce914 test`main(argc=1, argv=0x27dadd04) + 116 at main.m:16
    frame #15: 0x3a663ab6 libdyld.dylib`start + 2
```

I am trying to solve this crash but I am not able to get the reason for the crash as why it ios coming. Can anybody tell exactly what will be the issue as I am not getting this crash evertime.

Comment: set property to variable

Comment: unselector error you have faced

Comment: unclear question need more details

Comment: It appeared as if your array is already deallocated but you are trying to send message (objc_msgSend) to it again somewhere, hence receiving EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

Comment: Your code is clearing an autorelease pool and it's apparently encountered an object that is already released.  Is this ARC or manual reference counting?

Comment: (The autorelease pool being cleared is apparently one provided by the run loop in the main thread, not one you explicitly declared.  So basically you just somehow overreleased something.)

Answer (score 3):

This can just help you in sorting out where the crash is happening.

Just add a exception breakpoint so you can catch the error when it crashes.

After adding the breakpoint run the app again and test where it crashes. Almost this finds all the EXC_BAD_ACCESS crashes and puts the breakpoint in the line where the exception is caught.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

The Problem could be Something like You are assigning Some text Value to Label or button in some Thread.
If Yes you can't do this. You can only assign the Value in Main thread.